# Retrieve individuals with specific object property from OWL using Jena

Tags: java, jena, owl

I have class CloudService, and I created many individuals of this class. This is part of my CS.owl that shows an individual DropBox of class CloudService.

```
 <!-- language: xml -->

         <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/SaaS-24-03-2013.owl#DropBox -->
            <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&SaaS-24-03-2013;DropBox">
                <rdf:type rdf:resource="&SaaS-24-03-2013;CloudService"/>
                <hasPriceModel rdf:resource="&SaaS-24-03-2013;Freemium"/>
                <hasDeliveryModel rdf:resource="&SaaS-24-03-2013;Software-as-a-Service"/>
            </owl:NamedIndividual>
```

I need to retrieve individuals (such as DropBox) of class CloudService using Jena. I need to run it using Jena. Here is my code

```
  <!-- language: java -->

                String query = "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> "+
                                "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> "+
                                    "PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> "+
                                        "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> "+
                                            "PREFIX : <http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/SaaS-24-03-2013.owl#> "+
    "SELECT ?Service "+
                                            " WHERE {"+
                                        " ?Service  a   :CloudService "+                   
                                        ". ?Service  :hasPriceModel ?F. FILTER regex(str(?F), 'Freemium') }"; 
                   model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM_RULE_INF);
                        model.read("ontologies/CS.owl");
                Query query = QueryFactory.create(SparqlQuery);
                        QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
                        com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet results =  qe.execSelect();
    while(results.hasNext()) {
                QuerySolution qs = results.next();
                RDFNode x = qs.get("Service");
                System.out.println(x.asNode().getLocalName()); }
    qe.close();
                }
```

The query returns nothing, not even the column header
While it works correctly on Protege and returns many results (including DropBox)
What is wrong with my code?

Comment: @andys I have created new question

Comment: You didn't print the column headers so they don't appear.  Use ResultSetFormatter.

Comment: There are no solutions to the query. As to why that is, the fragment above does not have enough information.  Check the data. Check is it loaded. Start with a simple query like `SELECT ?Service { ?Service  :hasPriceModel ?F } LIMIT 5`

Comment: @AndyS When I run either ?Service  a   :CloudService  or   ?Service :hasPriceModel ?F  separately, it returns correct answer... The problem is when I try to combine two conditions in one query  ?Service  a   :CloudService. ?Service :hasPriceModel ?F , nothing is returned, although several individuals of class CloudService satisfy both condition e.g. DropBox

Comment: If the simple thing returns results and {  ?Service a :CloudService. ?Service :hasPriceModel ?F } does not, then there is nothing in the data matching both at the same time.  Check your data.

Comment: but the combined query (2 conditions) runs on protege and returns many results including DropBox shown above which matching both conditions... @AndyS